# only keep part of a list in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I have a Pandas series containing a list of strings like so:

```
series_of_list.head()
0 ['hello','there','my','name']
1 ['hello','hi','my','name']
2 ['hello','howdy','my','name']
3 ['hello','mate','my','name']
4 ['hello','hello','my','name']

type(series_of_list)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

I would like to only keep the first to entries of the list like so:

```
series_of_list.head()
0 ['hello','there']
1 ['hello','hi']
2 ['hello','howdy']
3 ['hello','mate']
4 ['hello','hello']
```

I have tried slicing it, `series_of_list=series_of_list[:2]`, but doing so just returns the first two indexes of the series...

```
 series_of_list.head()
 0 ['hello','there','my','name']
 1 ['hello','hi','my','name']
```

I have also tried `.drop` and other slicing but the outcome is not what I want.

How can I only keep the first two items of the list for the entire pandas series?

Thank you!

Comment: `series_of_list.str[:2]` ?

Answer (score 2):

[`pandas.Series.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) the function on each element.

```py
series_of_list = series_of_list.apply(lambda x: x[:2])
```